# Pytorch tutorial loss is not decreasing as expected

Tags: python, pytorch

I am reimplementing the pytorch tutorial of the [Pytorch cifar10 tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html)

But I want to use a different model.
I don't want to use fully connected (in pytorch linear) layers and I want to add Batch Normalization.

My model looks like this:

```
import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim

class Net(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
      super(Net, self).__init__()
      self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2,2)
      self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3,out_channels=16,kernel_size=3, padding=1, padding_mode='zeros')
      self.conv1_bn = nn.BatchNorm2d(16)
      self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=16,out_channels=32,kernel_size=3, padding=1, padding_mode='zeros')
      self.conv2_bn = nn.BatchNorm2d(32)
      self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32,out_channels=64,kernel_size=3, padding=1, padding_mode='zeros')
      self.conv3_bn = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
      self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(64,64,3, padding=1, padding_mode='zeros')
      self.conv4_bn = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
      self.conv5 = nn.Conv2d(64,10,2,padding=0)
  def forward(self, x): # x has shape (4,32,32,3)
      x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1_bn(self.conv1(x)))) # feature map resolution is now 16*16
      x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2_bn(self.conv2(x)))) # resolution now 8*8
      x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv3_bn(self.conv3(x)))) #resolution now 4*4
      x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv4_bn(self.conv4(x)))) # now 2*2
      x = F.relu(self.conv5(x)) # The output shape is (batchsize, 1,1,10)

      return x
```

Batchsize is 4 and image resolution is 32*32 so inputsize is 4,32,32,3
The convolution layers don't reduce the resolution size of the feature maps because of the padding. The resolution is halved with the maxpool layers. Conv5 gets an input with shape 4,2,2,64.
Now I use filtersize 2 and no padding to get a resolution of 1*1.
I have 10 classes so I use 10 filters. Each of the last filters should predict it's corresponding class.
The shape of the output is now (4,1,1,10).
But when I try to train this model the loss doesn't decrease. The amount of parameters of the tutorial model and my net are about the same at ~62k.

Here is the rest of the code. This is identical to the code in the tutorial but I have to reshape the output so it fits. (output in the tutorial was (4,10) and mine is 4,1,1,10)

```
transform = transforms.Compose(
    [transforms.ToTensor(),
     transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])
trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True,
                                        download=True, transform=transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=4,
                                          shuffle=True, num_workers=2)

testset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=False,
                                       download=True, transform=transform)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=4,
                                         shuffle=False, num_workers=2)

net = Net()
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.01, momentum=0.9)
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
net.to(device)
for epoch in range(2):  # loop over the dataset multiple times

  running_loss = 0.0
  for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
      # get the inputs; data is a list of [inputs, labels]
      inputs, labels = data[0].to(device), data[1].to(device)

      # zero the parameter gradients
      optimizer.zero_grad()

      # forward + backward + optimize
      outputs = net(inputs) # I get the values as 4,1,1,10
      outputs_reshaped = outputs.reshape(4,10)
      loss = criterion(outputs_reshaped, labels)
      loss.backward()
      optimizer.step()
      running_loss +=loss.item()
      if i % 2000 == 1999:    # print every 2000 mini-batches
          print('[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f' %
                (epoch + 1, i + 1, running_loss / 2000))
          running_loss = 0.0
```

My loss looks like this.

```
[1,  2000] loss: 2.348
[1,  2000] loss: 2.477
[1,  4000] loss: 2.482
[1,  6000] loss: 2.468
[1,  8000] loss: 2.471
[1, 10000] loss: 2.482
[1, 12000] loss: 2.485
[2,  2000] loss: 2.486
[2,  4000] loss: 2.470
[2,  6000] loss: 2.479
[2,  8000] loss: 2.481
[2, 10000] loss: 2.474
[2, 12000] loss: 2.470
```

My model doesn't seem to learn anything. Anyone an idea why this might happen?

Comment: I reproduced your example (tweaking a bit the code, there are typos here and there), and I don't even see a change in the loss: it is stuck at 2.303.

Comment: I changed the intendation so it's runnable with ctrl+c. With the learningrate of 0.01 it's stuck at 2.303. I changed the learningrate but this doesn't seem to be the problem. The loss I have written in the post was created with adam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your learning rate and momentum combination is too large for such a small batch size, try something like these:

```
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.01, momentum=0.0)
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
```

**Update**: I just realized another problem is you are using a relu activation at the end of the network. If you look at the documentation of [CrossEntropyLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#crossentropyloss), there is an advice:

> The input is expected to contain raw, unnormalized scores for each
>   class.

Try training your network by removing last relu from conv5 and keeping lr=0.01 and momentum=0.9. Relu before cross entropy loss throws away information about class scores.

Comment: I now use optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(),0.001) and it seems to work but it's training very slowly. Do you have any idea why this might be? loss: 2.270
loss: 2.260
loss: 2.253
loss: 2.250
loss: 2.232 while in the tutorial the loss decreases way faster

Comment: @relot I just realized I have another advice for you, I think its more important.

Comment: Funny we noticed the other problem at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

So if you have a similar problem
I changed the optimizer to

```
 optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(),0.001)
```

my last line in forward()
was

```
      x = F.relu(self.conv5(x))
```

I removed the relu, it's now

```
x= self.conv5(x)
```

and now the loss is decreasing as expected (way faster than the tutorial with the same amount of parameters)